# How do I access the associated Renderer object from within a QQuickFramebufferObject

Tags: c++, qt, qml, constants, qtquick2

I tried to store it as a member pointer on creation, so it can be accessed later:

```
QQuickFramebufferObject::Renderer* MyItem::createRenderer() const {
    m_renderer = new MyItemRenderer(this);
    return m_renderer;
}
```

... but this doesn't work - Qt requires `createRenderer` to be a const method, so I can't assign to m_renderer within it. I could use `mutable` but that's a hack and is risky because it may break assumptions in Qt internals.

Any proper way?

Comment: Btw, why do you need to do so?

Comment: @peppe: Because I'm implementing a system (called Snappy), similar to QtQuick, on top of QML; in my system, I want the renderers of child items to be able to access the renderer of SnappyScene (the SnappyScene contains all items in my system), because that way they can access its modelViewMatrixStack, its currentShader, etc. And to implement that access, I traverse pointers like this: SomeSnappyItemRenderer -> SomeSnappyItem -> SnappyScene -> SnappyScene::Renderer. And SnappyScene derives from QQFBO.

Comment: Conceptually, the design of QQFBO is to store all the state in the QQFBO subclass, the renderer accesses it and *copies* out the stuff it needs for rendering (copies because of multiple threads).

Comment: @peppe: I'm aware of that, but as my prev comment explains, this is not enough for my (admittedly unusual) usecase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thought of a way:

In `MyItemRenderer::synchronize` set the item's renderer to `this`. I don't like this very much, because it's abuse of `synchronize`, but it's certainly much better than `mutable`.

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```
QQuickFramebufferObject::Renderer* MyItem::createRenderer() const {
    return new MyItemRenderer();
}
```

More information [here](https://blog.qt.io/blog/2015/05/11/integrating-custom-opengl-rendering-with-qt-quick-via-qquickframebufferobject/). At the end of this page, it is stated the following:

> However, there is a special case when the FBO has to get recreated regardless: when moving the window to a screen with a different device pixel ratio. For example moving a window between a retina and non-retina screen on OS X systems will inherently need a new, double or half sized, framebuffer, even when the window dimensions are the same in device independent units. Just like with ordinary resizes, Qt is prepared to handle this by requesting a new framebuffer object with a different size when necessary. One possible pitfall here is the applications’ caching of the results of the factory functions: **avoid this**. **createFramebufferObject() and createRenderer() must never cache their return value**. Just create a new instance and return it. Keep it simple.

Comment: I'm not talking about *caching* though. *Caching* would mean returning the same Renderer object on several invocations of createRenderer. I'm talking about simply storing/accessing the renderer that I returned *last*.